# XSLT format number is returning false instead of comman format

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLT for consuming XML and then displaying it as html. It is working perfectly fine for me. But when I am adding format-number function in xslt ,it is showing false instead of some comma separated number.  Below is the code which i am using for doing this

XML:

```
<DATA>
  <PRICE>100000.56456</PRICE>
  <PRICE>9000000</PRICE>
 <PRICE>123333366.12325</PRICE>
</DATA>
```

XSLT Function :

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(/DATA/PRICE,'#,##,##,##,##,##,##0.00')" />
```

Now the output it is giving `false` instead of `1,00,000.56`

**Note** : i am using jquery.xslt.js  library for consuming xml into xslt.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your input XML with

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(/DATA/PRICE,'#,##,##,##,##,##,##0.00')" />
</xsl:template>
```

and the output is

```
100,000.56
```

Comment: Please check my updated question , i am using jquery.xslt as a library for consuming xml into xslt. Why i am getting false as output.